# Resize Android RadioGroup in ScrollView

Tags: java, android, radio-button, scrollview

I have a lot of RadioButtons (which are added dynamically through Java) in a RadioGroup which is in a ScrollView. The problem is that I don't know how to resize it so it fits on the screen. My code:

```
    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            btnEditFolder.setEnabled(true);
            btnViewFolder.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    for(int i =0; i<foldersArray.length;i++)
    {
        RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButtonView.setText(foldersArray[i]);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
    }
    ScrollView svFolders = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    radioGroup.setLayoutParams(params);
    radioGroup.getLayoutParams().height = screenHeight - 300;
    svFolders.setX(50);
    svFolders.setY(100 + btnEditFolder.getMeasuredHeight());
    svFolders.addView(radioGroup);
    layout.addView(svFolders, p);
```

The ScrollView is placed further down the y-axis and I think it's still the same height as the screen making it go off the screen.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvXp9.png)